# Jquery animate stops working on a specific element after a previous animation

Tags: jquery

I have been playing around with a small slider with HTML and Jquery. It's supposed to work by sliding off the screen, either left or right depending which way the user navigates, then returning via animation to it's original starting point.

Though as soon as i click the 'left' animation the 'right' animation wont animate anymore.

Clicking the 'right' animation has no effect on the 'left' animation, it still appears to work fine though visa versa it's a different story and i'm not sure why.

I have made a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1833boxm/2/) of my problem.

I have read an article on [Reset CSS Animation](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) but it doesn't seem to help me at all.

Maybe someone can help me spot what i'm missing

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- Product Slider -->
    <div id="index_slider_container" class="">

        <a id='slide_left' href'#'>left</a>

        <!-- Slider shaft -->
        <div id="slider_shaft" class="">
            <div id="slider_product_container" class="">

                <!-- Product Image -->
                <div id="slider_product_image" class="">

                </div>

                <!-- Product name -->
                <div id="slider_product_name" class="">

                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id='slide_right' href'#'>right</a>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
// Slider left
$("#slide_left").click( function(){

    $("#slider_shaft").css('left', '100%');

    // Set time out and return div VIA animation 
    setTimeout( function(){
        $("#slider_shaft").animate({left: '0%'}, 500);
    }, 200);

});

// Slider right
$("#slide_right").click( function(){

    $("#slider_shaft").css('right', '100%');

    // Set time out and return div VIA animation
    setTimeout( function(){
        $("#slider_shaft").animate({right: '0%'}, 500);
    }, 200);

});
```

**CSS**

```
#index_slider_container {
position: relative;
height: 120px;
width: 97%;
margin: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid;
text-align: center;
}

#slider_shaft {
position: relative;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
text-align: center;
}

#slider_product_container {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#slider_product_image {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
}

#slider_product_name {
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
}

#slide_left {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#slide_right {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the opposite direction to `auto`:

```
$("#slider_shaft").css('left', '100%');    
$("#slider_shaft").css('right', 'auto');
```

and

```
$("#slider_shaft").css('right', '100%');    
$("#slider_shaft").css('left', 'auto');
```

The problem is that the `left` attribute stays set, even after the Right button is clicked. You need to return it to default.

Comment: Thank you. What makes the left attribute stay set?

Comment: Simply put, you never told it to go back. A CSS attribute will stay the same unless it is manually changed. As Newton said, "A CSS attribute at rest stays at rest, unless acted upon by a Javascript script."